# PDF to Solr how to index the paragraphs of a PDF

Tags: solr

I'm working with Solr and I'm trying to find out how to index a bunch of PDF files and in the specific ingest paragraphs.
My PDF contains a paragraph as:

> Test (Some Test) -> Heading of the paragraph
>
> Some text -> Text of the paragraph

What I need to achieve is when I fire a search to Solr I should see a result the paragraph heading and the text related to it.

For example, I will search "keyword" and the result will be for this Keyword:

> Hello (Keyword)
>
> Paragraph whole text

I need a help with this as I have no idea how to do it.
I would like to know if I should use some external tool or what modification I need to do in Solr to achieve my results.

Answer (score 0):

You definitively need to do external work, if you use just solr, it will bundle all text it extracts into the same field, and you dont want that. So, you have to use Apache Tika/pdfbox or some other library to extract yourself the text (keeping headings and bodies separate), and index them into different fields.

This will have the additional result of the indeixng process being more resilient, as using built in Tika code in Solr is not recommended for very large indexing jobs.

Comment: Thanks, however, could you point me to some examples because I'm stuck with this. I would like to see an example of how to set that extraction. As an example I should be able to have this extracted from the PDF:
https://pastebin.com/MF8YPZce